# Retrieving public profile from Facebook with Firebase and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

So, I've been using Firebase in my AngularJS/Ionic project to access my app with Facebook authentication.

The authentication goes fine, it retrieves some data (Display_name, email, urid, url photo, etc.), but I need more.

I need to get the first name and last name  for my project, because I'll need to work with it. When the person accepts to share the information it says that she's sharing her public profile, but the data that comes doesn't have what Facebook documentation says that public profile provides.

[image: here]

I used Firebase documentation to program this. There's a part where it says to use `addScope` to add what you want, public profile is asked by default, but I added it anyway. (I can't post the link, StackOverflow says that my reputation is too low).

```
$scope.FBLogin = function (){
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  var user = result.user;
  var profile = result.user.public_profile;
  console.log("success")
  console.log(result);
  console.log(user);


}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
// ...
});
};
```

Log here:

[image: Log here]

So, since I don't want to have to use the "display name". as people sometimes don't use their real names there.

Does anyone know how to retrieve that information using Firebase and AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported by Firebase. You have to make the extra api call to Facebook to get that data.

result.credential.accessToken contains the Facebook access token. Using that access token, you can get facebook profile data. Here is an example how to do that with facebook:
[How to get user profile info using access token in php-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402343/how-to-get-user-profile-info-using-access-token-in-php-sdk)

AJAX GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + result.credential.accessToken

Comment: Thank you so much! =)
Thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for how to do it in AngularJS or how do you filter what you want this is how i did it using the information bojeil gave me!(Thank you again!)

```
var token = result.credential.accessToken;
var user = result.user;

$http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?  access_token='+token+'&fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email')
  .success(function(jsonService){
     $scope.user.firstName= jsonService.first_name;
     $scope.user.lastName= jsonService.last_name
     $scope.user.email = jsonService.email;
  });
```